# NPE with Ibatis/Java/MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, ibatis

I got an NPE when doing parameter-mapping with Java Character and Ibatis:

```
    insert into activity(id, is_delete) values (#id#, #isDelete#)
```

Property "isDelete" in DataObject is java.lang.Character

```
    private Character isDelete;
```

When I changed "isDelete" to java.lang.String, everything is OK.
What's the problem? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find a full list of supported Java types but around table 3 on this page http://ibatisnet.sourceforge.net/DevGuide.html you can see there are restrictions.  Believe if it's not supported out of the box you can write a custom type handler to do the conversion if need be.